# numpy splitting arrays column wise and stacking to each row

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, split, concatenation

I have a 2D array of dimension 12*80.

I want to split each row into subarrays of size 4 (total of 20 arrays) and stack the resulting arrays to the rows vertically.

Let us say that my array is

```
>>> A
array([[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3],
       [3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3]])
>>>
```

and I want to split each row into 3 subarrays and stack vertically.  My expected output is

```
>>> A
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3],
       [1, 3],
       [1, 3],
       [3, 1],
       [2, 1],
       [1, 3]])
>>>
```

Is there any other way other than iterating over and splitting each row one by one ?  A better efficient implementation ?

Comment: Does `A.reshape(-1, 2)` do the trick for you?

Comment: Yes, that exactly is what I am looking for. thanks